# Typescript: IntelliJ showing error when importing even when import is resolved correcty

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I'm working on an Angular project. I have a library `tools` and a project `example`. My project structure looks like this (Monorepo)

```
root
|-- projects
|   |-- example
|   |   |-- src
|   |   |   `-- app
|   |   |       |-- app.module.ts
|   |   |       `-- view
|   |   |           `-- main.component.ts
|   |   `-- tsconfig.app.json
|   `-- tools
`-- tsconfig.json
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my `tsconfig.app.json`

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "allowJs": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "traceResolution": true,
    "paths": {
      "tools": [
        "dist/tools/tools",
        "dist/tools"
      ],
      "@example/*": [
        "projects/example/src/app/*",
        "projects/example/src/app/view/features/*",
        "projects/example/src/app/core/guards/index.ts",
        "projects/example/src/app/core/components/index.ts",
        "projects/example/src/app/core/model/index.ts",
        "projects/example/src/app/core/services/index.ts",
        "projects/example/src/app/view/features/f1/store/index.ts",
        "projects/example/src/app/view/features/f2/store/index.ts",
        "projects/example/src/app/view/features/f3/store/index.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

When I try to import `tools` in my `app.module.ts`, it works fine. But when I import it in any of the feature/sub modules, say `main.component.ts`, IntelliJ marks it as an error.
`TS2307: Cannot find module 'tools' or its corresponding type declarations`

I tried to run `tsc --project projects/example/tsconfig.app.json` in the command line and examined the output, I found that it was resolved successfully
`Module name 'tools' was successfully resolved`

I'm clueless and out of solutions!

Comment: Might sound like a silly solution but have you tried closing Intellij and opening again ( this has worked for me in the past)

Comment: @Barkha yes many times, with invalidate cache and restart also. Didn't work :)

Comment: Is it possible to provide a sample project showing the issue? In general, the errors with TS-prefix come from the TS service and not from the IDE itself.

Comment: did you try to run the ngcc?

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your paths configuration into the root **tsconfig.json** instead of the project-specific **tsconfig.app.json**. This is actually where the Angular CLI library schematic (`ng g lib tools`) adds them.

---

To display type information for a particular file, IntelliJ will read the tsconfig that file "belongs to". This is determined by the `"files"`/`"include"`/`"exclude"` keys:

- Your **tsconfig.app.json** is currently configured to include `main.ts` and `polyfills.ts` (and any files referenced by them), or any `*.d.ts`.
- Your **tsconfig.json** will act as a catch-all for any other file.

Now, `app.module.ts` is referenced by `main.ts`, so it's part of **tsconfig.app.json**. Thus, within that file, IntelliJ is aware of the path mappings, and the `tools` import works just fine.

However, if you are doing your lazy routing correctly, `main.component.ts` is likely *not* directly imported by `main.ts`. It is now considered part of **tsconfig.json**, *NOT* **tsconfig.app.json**. Thus, within that file, IntelliJ has no idea about the path mappings, and the `tools` import throws.

(As a little test, try importing `main.component.ts` into `app.module.ts`. The `tools` import should immediately begin working in `main.component.ts`.)

When declared in **tsconfig.json**, the paths will work for any file, since **tsconfig.app.json** extends it.

---

**Side note:** You can actually *see* the tsconfig that IntelliJ uses for any particular file. Click the `TypeScript` button in the bottom status bar, then click Compile. You should see the file you're currently looking at, and the tsconfig that the file is part of. [Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gambZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete .project .settings .classpath folders ? I had something similar with my gradle project.

```
rm -rf .project .settings .classpath
```

Then I also tried after this opening the Settings > Invalidate Cache and Restart

Last case scenario I also had to clone and import the project again, and then perform the actions above.

Have a try, Intellij is always creating a lot of trash when building/compiling.